# asp.net mvc c# javascript web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to have retrieve a "imagetype" from appsettings in my web.config in javascript . how can i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use following code in your page markup:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var type = '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagetype"] %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagetype"];
```

You may find that for it to work you need to add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` if you don't already have one.

Create a new page, and in Page_Load put the line so that it all reads:

```
Response.Clear();
var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagetype"];
Response.Write(value);
Response.End();
```

You can now make an AJAX call to the page from Javascript, perhaps [using ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Connection.html#method-Ext.data.Connection-request) and the text will be returned to your javascript.

Alternatively, you could put the following into your page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var appSettingValue =  '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagetype"]%>';

  // The variable "appSettingValue" will contain the string from your web.config
  alert(appSettingValue);
</script>
```

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl, true, but the general gist is the same. For some reason my eyes stopped reading after "asp.net" - a long day today! =)